# How do you display data in 2 columns and 2 rows for a List which has aggregation Binding?

Tags: sapui5

In my view I have a List which has aggregation binding with a property from a model.
I want this to be displayed in the form of 2 columns and 2 rows. Which control should be used / layout?

In my code the model is set in the controller and has property question and answers where answers is a collection. This model is being binded to the List in the view.

Now I want to display this data in a layout where first two options are in first column and first row and then next 2 options in 2nd row i.e. 2 options with checkboxes per row.

At the moment my code for view, controller and my output looks like follows

**App.view.xml**

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:f="sap.ui.layout.form" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
displayBlock="true" controllerName="opensap.examples.controller.App" height="100%">
<Page title="List Page">
    <content>
        <List headerText="{myModel>/question}" id="myList" items="{myModel>/answers}">
            <items>
                <InputListItem label="{myModel>answerText}">
                    <CheckBox/>
                </InputListItem>
            </items>
        </List>
           <Button press="load" text="Click Me"/>
    </content>
</Page>
```

**App.controller.js**

```
sap.ui.define([
"sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
"sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"], function(Controller, JSONModel) {

var oData = {
    "question": "Which pet do you like from the following?",
    "answers": [{
        "answerText": "Cats"
    }, {
        "answerText": "Rabbits"
    }, {
        "answerText": "Dogs"
    }, {
        "answerText": "Hamsters"
    }]
};

var oModel;

Controller.extend("opensap.examples.controller.App", {

    onInit: function() {
        oModel = new JSONModel();
        oModel.setData(oData);
        this.getView().setModel(oModel, "myModel");


    },
    load: function() {
        console.log(oModel);
    }

});
});
```

**Output:** [image: Output2]

**What is needed:**  To display Cats and Rabbits answers one one row and Dogs and hamsters on next one i.e. 2 items with checkboxes on one row and so on.

Which control should one use for this? I need a control with aggregation binding.

Comment: loki, if you want to show data by a 2x2 matrix, you need the sap.m.table. you can find many useful stuff here https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/ I prefer the "Explored" and API-Reference section. The API-Reference is a bit hard to read, because you cannot search for function names, but classes.

Comment: @corax228 you are the person who taught me the use of aggregation binding. Now I can use aggregation binding with some confidence. Thank you very much for that. And yes it is bit difficult to understand API. I hope matt understands my problem and let this go. Because of the knowledge I am gaining I answered someone with SAPUI5 query yesterday and it was my first answer which got accepted. It is confidence builder I hope to learn and in some time start helping others this way.

Comment: @loki, it really helped me to understand, API search is only available for class-names. these class-names are equivalent to the names provided by the "Explored"-Section. Play around with these two a bit and you will understand, how SAP sees the development world :) give it a try ;)

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to restructure your data. Each item in the list binding can only represent one item in the data. There's no (easy) way to combine two objects in the data into one item in the list when you're using aggregation binding. Then you can either use a Table with a ColumnListItem to separate the columns, or use a CustomListItem like I've done here.

Try this:

View:

```
<mvc:View xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" xmlns="sap.m" controllerName="opensap.examples.controller.App" height="100%">
    <Page title="List Page">
        <content>
            <List headerText="{myModel>/question}" id="myList" items="{myModel>/answers}">
                <items>
                    <CustomListItem>
                        <FlexBox justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                            <Text text="{myModel>answerText1}"/>
                            <CheckBox/>
                        </FlexBox>
                        <FlexBox justifyContent="SpaceBetween">
                            <Text text="{myModel>answerText2}"/>
                            <CheckBox/>
                        </FlexBox>
                    </CustomListItem>
                </items>
            </List>
            <Button press="load" text="Click Me"/>
        </content>
    </Page>
</mvc:View>
```

Controller:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
    "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function(Controller, JSONModel) {

    var oData = {
        "question": "Which pet do you like from the following?",
        "answers": [{
            "answerText1": "Cats",
            "answerText2": "Rabbits"
        }, {
            "answerText1": "Dogs",
            "answerText2": "Hamsters"
        }]
    };
    var oModel;
    Controller.extend("opensap.examples.controller.App", {
        onInit: function() {
            oModel = new JSONModel();
            oModel.setData(oData);
            this.getView().setModel(oModel, "myModel");
        },
        load: function() {
            console.log(oModel);
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Kyle. I see you also restructured the answers property in Model. I will give it a try.  It was just something extra I wanted to learn. Thank you for letting me know the usage of CustomListItem.